ubuntu gnome-terminal is laggy
problem:
Everything other than gnome-terminal is fine as far as i have seen.
In gnome-terminal when i type it feels laggy, like it has high ping feeling.
It only happens when its fullscreen mode.
i used warp terminal too it does not have the problem.
things i have tried:

i have update  my bios to the latest version
(https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B550-AORUS-PRO-AC-rev-1x/support#support-dl-bios)
reinstalled the ubuntu 22.04

my hardware specs:
aourus b550 pro ac,
gigabyte rtx 3060ti,
MD Ryzen 7 5800X 8-Core Processor

Does this answer your question? input delay on Terminal Ubuntu 22.04.4
